# Outlook 365 white gaps

Tags: outlook

I'm struggling with a problem in the Outlook 365 client, that I hope you can help me with.

I have a very simple table setup with some space in top, and 365 thinks it should insert white lines in top and bottom:
https://www.screencast.com/t/mWFj57wIGx

Here is the complete code example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head>

    <title>Email Framework Version 1.0.1</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <style type="text/css">
        .ReadMsgBody {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #F6F6F6;
        }
        
        .ExternalClass {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #F6F6F6;
        }
        
        body {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f6f6f6;
            margin: 0;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            font-family: Arial, Times, serif
        }
        
        h1,
        h2,
        h3,
        p,
        td {
            line-height: normal !important;
        }
        
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt;
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 639px) {
            .wrapper {
                width: 100%;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
        }
        
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .centerClass {
                margin: 0 auto !important;
            }
            .imgClass {
                width: 100% !important;
                height: auto;
            }
            .wrapper {
                width: 320px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
            .header {
                width: 320px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
                background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/320x400/fff/fff) !important;
            }
            .container {
                width: 300px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
            }
            .mobile {
                width: 300px !important;
                display: block !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
                text-align: center !important;
            }
            .mobile25 {
                width: 150px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
                text-align: center;
                display: inline-table;
            }
            .mobile50 {
                width: 300px !important;
                padding: 0 !important;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .mobileOff {
                width: 0px !important;
                display: none !important;
            }
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" style="background-color:#F6F6F6; font-family:Arial,serif; margin:0; padding:0; min-width: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:none; -ms-text-size-adjust:none;">

    <!-- Start Background -->
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%" valign="top" align="center">

                <!-- Start TEST -->
                <table width="760" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#111111">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;"> </td>
                        <!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container -->
                            <table width="720" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="360" class="mobile" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; color:#fff; line-height:18px; margin:0;" align="center">
                                        Menu 1
                                    </td>
                                    <td width="360" class="mobile" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; color:#fff; line-height:18px; margin:0;" align="center">
                                        Menu 2
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- End Container -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="20" style="font-size:20px; line-height:20px;"> </td>
                        <!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- End TEST -->

                <!-- Start Content -->
                <table width="760" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                    <tr>
                        <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td>
                        <!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">

                            <!-- Start Container -->
                            <table width="720" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container">
                                <tr>
                                    <td width="720" class="mobile" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; line-height:18px; margin:0;">
                                        {content}
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                            <!-- End Container -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="10" style="font-size:10px; line-height:10px;"> </td>
                        <!-- Spacer -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <!-- End Content -->

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Background -->

</body>

</html>
```

Does anyone know what I can do to remove these white lines?

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news, the current thinking is that there is no way to fix this issue with Outlook.

Outlook 2007/2010/2013/2016 Windows 10 Mail and maybe every Office client (I could not test in 365) adds space to the body of the email message. It will add a 15px space to the top and bottom of an email and 10px spacing to the left and right sides.

This is the drawback to HTML Email. Since there are no standards, each email client has a different set of standards they support or quirks they add.

Don't take my post as discouragement, see it as the rest of us simply have not found a solution. Maybe you will discover a solution to this problem. In most clients, there will be no gap.

Good Luck.

Also, thank you for posting your code snippet. It allows people to easily test your code to see if we can find some solution, if available.